# How to select specific element from g and transform it

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

I'm working slowly through an example of building up my first visualisation in d3, and I'm now stumped with how to select a specific object within a 'g' grouping and displaying in a different way from others.

You can see my working chart so far here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aYJjwvNPcbDGQdUu6SOJ?p=preview

Essentially, the chart aims to display the average selling price of certain types of district, with a select switch to move between areas.

Unfortunately, there are two problems that I'm struggling to work out.

1. The initial bar levels for the first selected area 'Cannock Chase' are higher than they should be, and drop back down if you return the selection to it.
2. My original aim was to display a horizontal line on the chart to represent the average price of all sales in a district.

It's currently displayed as a rect in the chart. How can I select that last 'rect'?

It should start with:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
```

But then I can't work out how to pick the last given there's no 'id'. Is that something I should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bar Heights**

The reason for your bar height difference is because your initial attribute setting for y and height are different from the ones you have in the change handler

You have in the first one

```
  .attr("y", function(d){
    return height - price_scale(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return price_scale(d.value);
  })
```

and in the latter

```
  .attr("y", function(d){
    return price_scale(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - price_scale(d.value);
  })
```

The functions for y and height are swapped. If you make them the same the heights will remain the same

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/3SO6s1Kah43dwTASCvX2?p=preview

---

**Styling**

The good part about using SVG is that you can use CSS for styling. If you just want to style the last bar differently you can use

```
 svg rect:last-child {
    fill: red;
 }
```

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/9OBw1Okmde73eyXZRVXX?p=preview

Note that you probably want to set an id for your svg element and a class for your bars for when you have other elements or multiple charts.

---

However I assume you are asking about doing it with d3. You could use the same selector

```
d3.select('svg rect:last-child').style('fill', 'red')
```

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/RrLEJa4ZCIEOGSVD4stL?p=preview

---

However if you were thinking about doing this in a more of a d3 way, you'd want to actually use your data model to indicate that the last data point was something special and use that to style it differentl.

Here's one way where we use the special value 'AVERAGE' to figure out that we need to style a bar differently (you could instead add a special property to your data instead)

```
...
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.street_split === 'AVERAGE')
        return 'red'
    else
        return "steelblue"
});
```

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/8Xt5xX2i2WF6nazoZCeo?p=preview

Comment: That's great. I really appreciate your time, particularly the last bit. I've learned to mung data with Python Pandas and am struggling to get used to manipulating data with Javascript. I'll keep plugging. Thank you again :)